# Why execution time is showing 0 milliseconds(java program )?

Tags: java

> I am writing a word count program (very basic) and try to find its
>   execution time . What is strange is that sometime it shows
>   `0 milliseconds` after execution of same input for which earlier it gave
>   `15 milliseconds`.
>
> Moreover sometime it shows 16 milliseconds and sometime 15
>   milliseconds for same input.Why is that variance?  What could be the
>   possible reason for it?

Here is the program:

```
import java.util.*;


public class WordCount{

        public static void main(String [] args){

            Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enetr the Line of String");
            String words=scan.nextLine();
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            wordCount(words);


            long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println("\n TotalTime =  "+totalTime + " mills");

        }//main

        public static  void wordCount(String words){
            Integer c=0;
            String wor[]=words.split(" ");

            //System.out.println(""+Arrays.toString(wor));


            HashMap<String,Integer> hm=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            for(String word: wor){
                // c=(Integer)hm.get(word);
                  c=hm.get(word);
                c=(c==null)?1:c+1;    //no c++
                hm.put(word,c);
            }

            Set keySet=hm.keySet();

            Iterator it=keySet.iterator();

            while(it.hasNext()){
                String key=(String)it.next();

                System.out.println(""+key+" = " + hm.get(key));
            }


        }//wordCount

 }//class
```

> Output screen :

```
H:\Computer Science\Java>java WordCount
Enetr the Line of String
the is an the is an a is an the
the = 3
a = 1
is = 3
an = 3

 TotalTime =  15 mills

H:\Computer Science\Java>java WordCount
Enetr the Line of String
the is an the is an a is an the
the = 3
a = 1
is = 3
an = 3

 TotalTime =  16 mills

H:\Computer Science\Java>java WordCount
Enetr the Line of String
the is an the is an a is an the
the = 3
a = 1
is = 3
an = 3

 TotalTime =  0 mills

H:\Computer Science\Java>java WordCount
Enetr the Line of String
the is an the is an a is an the
the = 3
a = 1
is = 3
an = 3

 TotalTime =  0 mills
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `System.currentTimeMillis()` [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29) we read that the method:

> Returns the current time in milliseconds. Note that while the unit of
>   time of the return value is a millisecond, **the granularity of the
>   value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger**.
>   For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of
>   milliseconds.

For Windows the resolution time for this method is longer than 1ms (in your case around 16ms) and this is a minimum time needed to update the timer. What this mean is that when you call `System.currentTimeMillis()` twice you get either two exactly same results (that explains 0) or two results which differ by amount of time needed to resolute time on your operating system.

Consider using `System.nanoTime()` instead `System.currentTimeMillis()`. It produces more precise results. You can read more about time measurement at [the Oracle blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks) which concludes with the following paragraph:

> If you are interested in measuring/calculating elapsed time, then
>   always use System.nanoTime(). On most systems it will give a
>   resolution on the order of microseconds. Be aware though, this call
>   can also take microseconds to execute on some platforms.

Comment: Yes I know about that. but what is the reason for showing 0 milliseconds? It shouldn't be 0 as per I know or is there a catch?

Comment: I appreciate your answer but my question is different. I know about System.nanoTime() . Thanks

Comment: On windows the resolution is 64 / second which is 15.625 ms. For that reason you get only multiples of 15 ms. I assume some rounding stuff at the results 15 and 16 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Execution time of your program is computationally 0. Counting words in a small sentence does not take time in milliseconds range. You are sometimes getting 15ms or 16ms most probably because of I/O (System.out), operating systems scheduling delays, other programs working on your system, or limitations of  `System.currentTimeInMillis()` implementation. Actual working time of your word count program should be 0, take out the I/O.

Comment: But why then the variance of 15 and 0. It should be 15 always or 0.isn't that?

Comment: all I/O operations are unpredictable, it may be immediate or delayed due to other I/O operations. It may be something else too, it is difficult to know.